# DOM children property gets elements, but without their classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to select all the children of a `<select>` element using the `.children` DOM property. While the children are being returned, when I try to check whether they have a class or when I log them to the console, no class is being shown, even though they have multiple classes in the mark-up.

Structure of `select`:

```
<select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="blue" class="attached" disabled="">Blue</option>
    <option value="gray" class="attached enabled">Gray</option>
    <option value="green" class="attached" disabled="">Green</option>
    <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="attached enabled">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

How I select the children:

```
var selects = $(".variations").find("select");
var selectOpts = selects[i].children;
console.log(selectOpts);
```

What is shown on the console:

[image]

EDIT: It would appear that this only happens when I console log individual children, as in `console.log(selectOpts[2])` would show `<option value="gray">Gray</option>`, but `console.log(selectOpts)` shows all of them with their classes.

Comment: There are classes, just use `console.dir` instead fo `console.log` to see them.

Comment: On SO, it's not okay to edit the question once answers have been posted such that the edit invalidates the answer(s), as you've just done. I won't roll it back because it does make more sense with the edit, but please remember for next time. (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: @TheUnreal Even though the `.hasClass()` function returns false for all of them, I tried with `console.dir` and there's nothing in `className`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pass some data using class, did you try using data-attr? Like: `<option value="green" data-some="attached">Green</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Your quoted code is too fragmentary to really be sure about what's wrong with it, but the child elements **do** have the classes. It would appear that whatever display you're quoting isn't showing them for some reason (which is odd), but they are there:

```js
var selects = $(".variations").find("select");
var i = 0; // Our example has only one
var selectOpts = selects[i].children;
for (var n = 0; n < selectOpts.length; ++n) {
  console.log("child " + n + " className: " + selectOpts[n].className);
}
```

```html
<div class="variations">
  <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
      <option value="">Choose an option</option>
      <option value="blue" class="attached" disabled="">Blue</option>
      <option value="gray" class="attached enabled">Gray</option>
      <option value="green" class="attached" disabled="">Green</option>
      <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
      <option value="yellow" class="attached enabled">Yellow</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly added an index for the first child. My actual code is console logging all of the children without classes, as seen in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are trying to collect the classNames of the `<option>` tags

**Using JQuery**

```js
const children = $("#pa_color").children();
const classNames = children.map((index,item) => $(item).attr("class"))
console.log(classNames)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations">
  <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="blue" class="attached" disabled="">Blue</option>
    <option value="gray" class="attached enabled">Gray</option>
    <option value="green" class="attached" disabled="">Green</option>
    <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="attached enabled">Yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Without JQuery**

```js
const element = document.getElementById("pa_color");
const children = [].slice.call(element.children);
const classNames = children.map( child => child.className);
console.log(classNames)
```

```html
<div class="variations">
  <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="blue" class="attached" disabled="">Blue</option>
    <option value="gray" class="attached enabled">Gray</option>
    <option value="green" class="attached" disabled="">Green</option>
    <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="attached enabled">Yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
```